# Explorer like ListView

Tags: c++, windows, api, listview

In explorer the file lists background color, and selection color is a light blue.

I have a List-View in my application with `LVS_REPORT` style, is there any way to get the same colors, instead of a solid blue?

Comment: Custom Draw List View: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364048%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#customdraw_topic4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out using the `SetWindowTheme` function.

Example:

```
SetWindowTheme(hWndListView, TEXT("Explorer"), NULL);
```